# Where can I find a collection Of Ruby Gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Where can I find a collection of free available Ruby gems? 
Why reinvent the wheel if a gem is already available that you can re-use?

Comment: Tower of London?  They're not free, however. :-)

Comment: Your question makes me wonder if there's an Amazon.com for gems where people can give ratings and reviews of gems. (Apart from isitruby19.com)

Answer (score 3):

[RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/) is the place to go.

Answer (score 2):

There are really only two important sources for gems available:

1. [RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org)
2. [GitHub](http://github.com/)

Comment: As much git and github are cool and awesome and everything, I miss having one canonical place to look for gems.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of RubyGems at GitHub:

```
http://gems.github.com/list.html
```

Instructions on how to download are at the top of the page. It's no CPAN though...

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia says:

```
gem list -r -d
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems